# Bootstrap 4 - Why is 'col-sm-auto' overriding 'col-md-4'?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am learning Bootstrap and now I am facing a problem that I just couldn't get it.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
<button 
  className="
       col-md-4 
       col-sm-auto 
       btn 
       btn-info 
       btn-custom" 
  onClick={this.toggleModalHandler}
> Salvar
</button>
```

Here a somewhat more complete code:

```
<div className="container">
                <h2 className="border-bottom mb-4 pt-sm-2">Insira Os Valores Do Produto</h2>
                <div className="pt-4 border-bottom">
                    <h5>Valor Total: R$ </h5>
                    <div className="
                            row
                            align-items-md-center 
                            mb-2 
                            flex-md-row
                            flex-sm-column" 
                        >
                        <h5 className="col-md-4 col-sm-auto mb-md-0">Valor Total Acumulado: R$</h5>
                        <div className="col-md-8 col-sd-12">
                            <button 
                                className="col-auto btn btn-success btn-custom" 
                                onClick={() => this.addOrcHandler()}
                            > Adicionar Orçamento
                            </button> 
                            <button 
                                className="col-auto btn btn-danger btn-custom" 
                                onClick={() => this.limparHistoricoOrcHandler()}
                            > Limpar Orçamentos
                            </button>
                            <button 
                                className="col-md-4 col-sm-auto col-3 btn btn-info btn-custom" 
                                onClick={this.toggleModalHandler}
                            > Salvar
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As I understand it so far `col-md-4` should override `col-sm-auto` when the screen is bigger than `768px`, but it is not working and I don't know why, since it worked properly in other elements.

[image]

[image]

I couldn't find an answer to this specific situation on my researches.

What I am not getting is why `col-md-4` is not ocuppying 4 columns of the grid.

Just an observation: It works fine if I remove `col-sm-auto`. And it is in a `row`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does. That's why the `col-sm-auto` entry has properties crossed out when they are overridden!!

Comment: In your image shown  the `col-md-4` ovveride some properties of `col-sm-auto`. just as expected. not the opposite..

Comment: @Yosef Tukachinsky yes, but as you see, the width is `auto`, that is the point I am no understandind and my `button` is receiving it and not `col-4`. That's where I got lost.

Comment: The `width` is auto, since in the `col-md-4` class there is no given value for `width`. only for `max-width`. if the `col-md-4` class has give any value for `width` - it was override the value from the `sm-auto`

Comment: if you give same classes to a `display:block` element, which `auto` is `100%` it will do what you (most likely) trying to archive

Comment: @ Yosef Tukachinsky I see. I could do that, no problem. But the point is, if I am using `col-md-4` shouldn't it occupy 4 columns of the grid regardles the `width` property? That is what is troubling me.

Comment: @Berg_Durden — Yes, the `flex` property sets it to take up 33% of the width

Comment: Wild speculation, since you didn't provide an [mcve]: You didn't put the columns in a *row*.

Comment: Re edit: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin 33%, that's what I expect, but not what I am getting. And yes, I put it in a `row`. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Quentin `Provide a minimal reproducible example `. I just did that, I guess now it's possible to have a better idea of what I need

Comment: @Berg_Durden: The buttons aren't in a row. They are in another column.

Comment: @Quentin I see. So I misunderstood this point, I have thought that the first row would encompass all children. I'll correct that and see what I get.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, it was just that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You see, the `.col` uses for blocks which are the part of [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). For correct work they should be covered in `.row` and `.container` parents. Although, you shouldn't mix it with `button` and `.btn`, because they works with different logic and for different purpose. The correct code is:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-custom btn-block">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

More about `.col` wrapping https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#column-wrapping

Added `.btn-block` for `.btn` to get them 100% in a parent `.col`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2 class="border-bottom mb-4 pt-sm-2">Insira Os Valores Do Produto</h2>
  <div class="pt-4 border-bottom">
    <h5>Valor Total: R$ </h5>
    <div class="row align-items-md-center mb-2 flex-md-row flex-sm-column">
      <h5 class="col-md-4 col-sm-auto mb-md-0">Valor Total Acumulado: R$</h5>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sd-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-custom btn-block">Adicionar Orçamento</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-custom btn-block">Limpar Orçamentos</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-custom btn-block">Salvar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why downvote? Try to rewrite your code according to these BS rules and everything will work perfectly. ` btn-block` this you will need to do `btn` `display: block;`. Separate `.col` form `.btn`

Comment: Although you can try combination like `col-sm-4 col-auto`

Comment: I did what you're saying but it is not working well. I'll try to adjust if I don't solve it the way I need. And just an observation, the downvote was not mine.

Comment: Updated the answer according to your new code. Look please.

Comment: I wrote about covering `.col` with `.row` at the beginning of the answer...

Comment: Just putting the buttons inside a `row` solved the problem. I had misunderstood and thought that the first `row` would affect all children and it seems that I was wrong. About what you said concerning to mixing button and grid classes I'll check it out and I'll improve my code as everything gets more clear to me. As I said, I've just started learning and I am following step by step, the simple ones first. Anyway, thank you for your time and knowledge.